# Webpack add JS library

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "**",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "**",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jplayer": "2.9.2",
    "jquery-ui": "1.12.1",
    "owl.carousel": "2.2.0",
    "wowjs": "1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "2.3.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "0.1.16",
    "babel-core": "6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "uglify-js": "2.8.21",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "style-loader": "0.16.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.0",
    "url-loader": "0.5.8",
    "stylefmt": "5.3.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "purifycss-webpack": "0.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:dist": "webpack --env=prod --config=webpack.config.js",
    "build:dev": "webpack-dev-server --env=dev --config=webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function (env) {
  return {
    devServer: {
      inline: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
      landing: [
        './node_modules/wowjs',
        './js/landing.js'
      ]
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/'),
      filename: 'js/[name].js',
      chunkFilename: '[id].js'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['es2015'],
              plugins: ['transform-runtime']
            }
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: ['css-loader']
          })
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.(eot|woff|ttf|svg|png|jpg)$/,
          use: 'url-loader?limit=50000&name=assets/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(['app']),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        _: 'lodash'
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: (getPath) => {
          return getPath('css/[name].css');
        },
        allChunks: true
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        chunks: ['landing', 'bundle'],
        favicon: './img/favicon.png',
        template: './pages/index.html',
        inject: true
      }),
      new CommonsChunkPlugin('bundle')
    ]
  };
};
```

**landing.js:**

```
$(() => {
  const wow = new WOW({
    boxClass: 'wow',
    animateClass: 'animated',
    offset: 100,
    mobile: false
  });
  wow.init();
});
```

I used the command: webpack --env=prod --config=webpack.config.js

After running the command I open the page /app/index.html in the browser

But the error on the page:
Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, the package is named `wowjs`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when your'e bundles are being made. Somewhere in there, your JS references `WOW` object. As at the moment there is no DOM present, `WOW` is not attached to the DOM and hence you see the error.

The solution is to use the [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) which make the reference a valid one whenever it is made by any chunk. As described in the documentation :

> Automatically loads modules. Whenever the `identifier` is encountered as free variable in a module, the `module` is loaded automatically and the `identifier` is filled with the exports of the loaded `module`.

In your case you can add the following snippet and it'll work

```
    plugins: [
    ....
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        WOW: 'wowjs',
      })
    ]
```

*EDIT: *
The value you pass to the `ProvidePlugin` is the one who's module is loaded

So for

```
import 'jquery';
```

you'd use

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
})
```

Under the hood, plugin searches for `jquery` module imported somewhere and makes the reference available.

To answer your comment. If you've use `import 'wowjs'` you'll have to pass `wowjs` to the plugin as the value for `WOW`

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    WOW: 'wowjs',
})
```

Sorry for missing out on this part, I had assumed that you would have imported it as `wow` instead of `wowjs` as that's the correct way to do it.

```
import * as wow from "wowjs"
```

In any case, you can use the previous snippet and you should be good to go.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "WOW"

Comment: @user5671335, can you share the `import` or the `require` statement for WOW that your'e using